# Pinescript v1 to v4 conversion

Tags: pine-script

I have been trying to convert this to v4 but having a lot of issues, particularly with errors r Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have looked at the V3 conversion guide. Thanks in advance for any help.
Coral Trend Indicator Buy-Sell with Alarm by coinsspor. You can setup BUY-SELL alarm.

```
study("Coral Trend Indicator [LazyBear] Buy-Sell with Alarm by coinsspor", overlay=true)
src=close
sm =input(21, title="Smoothing Period")
cd = input(0.4, title="Constant D")
ebc=input(false, title="Color Bars")
ribm=input(false, title="Ribbon Mode")
di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
c2 = 1 - c1
c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd
i1 = c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1])
i2 = c1*i1 + c2*nz(i2[1])
i3 = c1*i2 + c2*nz(i3[1])
i4 = c1*i3 + c2*nz(i4[1])
i5 = c1*i4 + c2*nz(i5[1])
i6 = c1*i5 + c2*nz(i6[1])

bfr = -cd*cd*cd*i6 + c3*(i5) + c4*(i4) + c5*(i3)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// For the Pinescript coders: Determining trend based on the mintick step. 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//bfrC = bfr - nz(bfr[1]) > syminfo.mintick ? green : bfr - nz(bfr[1]) < syminfo.mintick ? red : blue
bfrC = bfr > nz(bfr[1]) ? green : bfr < nz(bfr[1])  ? red : blue
tc=ebc?gray:bfrC
plot(ribm?na:bfr, title="Trend", linewidth=3, style=circles, color=tc)
bgcolor(ribm?bfrC:na, transp=50)
barcolor(ebc?bfrC:na)
KDbuy=bfr > nz(bfr[1])
KDsell= bfr < nz(bfr[1])
//last_signal= 0
long_final  = KDbuy  and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == -1)
short_final = KDsell and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == 1)
alertcondition(long_final, title="BUY ALARM", message="Coral Trend Buy Alarm!!!")
alertcondition(short_final, title="SELL ALARM", message="Coral Trend Sell Alarm!!!")

bgcolor( (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == -1) ? green : red, transp=93)

bgcolor( long_final? green : na, transp=93)
bgcolor( short_final? red : na, transp=93)



last_signal= long_final ? 1 : short_final ? -1 : last_signal[1]

plotshape(long_final, style=shape.labelup,
          location=location.belowbar, color=green,size=size.tiny,title="buy label",text="BUY",textcolor=white)
plotshape(short_final, style=shape.labeldown,
          location=location.abovebar, color=red,size=size.tiny,title="sell label",text="SELL",textcolor=white)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//@version=4

study("Coral Trend Indicator [LazyBear] Buy-Sell with Alarm by coinsspor", overlay=true)
src=close
sm =input(21, title="Smoothing Period")
cd = input(0.4, title="Constant D")
ebc=input(false, title="Color Bars")
ribm=input(false, title="Ribbon Mode")


var float di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
var float c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
var float c2 = 1 - c1
var float c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
var float c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
var float c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd

var float i1 = na, var float i2 = na, var float i3 = na, var float i4 = na, var float i5 = na, var float i6 = na
i1 := c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1])
i2 := c1*i1 + c2*nz(i2[1])
i3 := c1*i2 + c2*nz(i3[1])
i4 := c1*i3 + c2*nz(i4[1])
i5 := c1*i4 + c2*nz(i5[1])
i6 := c1*i5 + c2*nz(i6[1])

var float bfr = na
bfr := -cd*cd*cd*i6 + c3*(i5) + c4*(i4) + c5*(i3)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// For the Pinescript coders: Determining trend based on the mintick step. 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//bfrC = bfr - nz(bfr[1]) > syminfo.mintick ? green : bfr - nz(bfr[1]) < syminfo.mintick ? red : blue
var color bfrC = bfr > nz(bfr[1]) ? color.green : bfr < nz(bfr[1])  ? color.red : color.blue
tc=ebc?color.gray:bfrC
plot(ribm?na:bfr, title="Trend", linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles, color=tc)
bgcolor(ribm?bfrC:na, transp=50)
barcolor(ebc?bfrC:na)
KDbuy=bfr > nz(bfr[1])
KDsell= bfr < nz(bfr[1])
var last_signal = 0
long_final  = KDbuy  and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == -1)
short_final = KDsell and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == 1)
alertcondition(long_final, title="BUY ALARM", message="Coral Trend Buy Alarm!!!")
alertcondition(short_final, title="SELL ALARM", message="Coral Trend Sell Alarm!!!")

bgcolor( (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == -1) ? color.green : color.red, transp=93)

bgcolor( long_final? color.green : na, transp=93)
bgcolor( short_final? color.red : na, transp=93)



last_signal := long_final ? 1 : short_final ? -1 : last_signal[1]

plotshape(long_final, style=shape.labelup,
          location=location.belowbar, color=color.green,size=size.tiny,title="buy label",text="BUY",textcolor=color.white)
plotshape(short_final, style=shape.labeldown,
          location=location.abovebar, color=color.red,size=size.tiny,title="sell label",text="SELL",textcolor=color.white)
```